# Fetching more products from the server on scroll

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have an app that I was able to implement the infinite scroll when the user is scrolling to the bottom of the Products component and then it shows 10 more products.
Now what I'm trying to achieve is once the app is loaded I want to fetch 10 products from the server and another 10 once scrolling to the Product component.
What happens now is that the entire 20 products are fetched immediately on load.

How can I fix that?
Thank you.

```
const Products = ({ cat, filters, sort }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);
  const [productCount, setProductCount] = useState(10);


const myRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axiosInstance.get(
          cat
            ? `http://localhost:5000/api/products?category=${cat}`
            : "http://localhost:5000/api/products/"
        );
        console.log(res.data);
        setProducts(res.data);

      } catch (err) {}
    };
    getProducts();
  }, [cat]);

 const handleScroll = () => {
    if (
      myRef.current &&
      myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight
    ) {
      setProductCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 10);
    }
  };

 useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
   return () => {
     window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
   };
 }, []);

........

 <Container ref={myRef}>
```

Comment: are you using the "react-infinite-scroller" ?

Comment: No, i'm not. I edited my post and added the handle scroll function.